# How to modify variable in one file from another

Tags: node.js, express

My log.js,

```
  var data ;
var winston = require('winston');
var config =  {'status':1};
module.exports.config = config;
```

My get.js file(from where i want to modify log.js),

```
   exports.getcategories = function (req, res) {
 if(log.status == 1){
  var data = 'loaded successfully';
 }
};
```

Here i want to modify my data variable in log.js from my get.js,can anyone please suggest help.

Comment: You don't modify it directly. You either expose a setter, or pass the variable around. Since you declare data only in the if, it is not only useless, but impratical. Please explain what your goal is and why you need to edit data.

Comment: You can't modify it either ways until and unless you expose the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on Javascript scopes. In order to access *any* variable in a file or function from outside it, there are only two ways:

1. Make the variable global (**NOT** a good idea).
2. Create  getter/setter functions and export them, thereby exposing it to the outside world